# is it true that Building with JDK8 makes the app not works on older Android OS versions?

Tags: android, xamarin

I am using JDK8x64 (only) with Android Studio 2.1 and targeting Android 4+.
Here I think this JDK8x64 used for build system itself, not for exporting to Android. (So it is OK, because Java 8 is backward compatible). (OS: Win7x64)
But according to: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/48581/use-of-jdk-8-with-xamarin-android
Is it true that Building with JDK8 makes the app not works on older Android OS versions?
Any experience?
And what about JDK 8 with Xamarin Android?

Comment: I cant speak for xamarin specifically but android studio's compiler handles all that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We been using v8 since it was released and have not had any problems within Xamarin.Android apps (or Java binding libraries):

```
>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_92
```

---

```
>java -version
java version "1.8.0_92"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)
```

#### That said, Xamarin website does state:

#### OS-X Requirements

> Xamarin.Android requires the following for use with Xamarin Studio on a Mac:
>
> Java JDK 7 (1.7)
>
> If you are developing solely for Android versions older than Android 5.0 Lollipop (API 21), Java JDK 6 (1.6) can still be used. Later versions of the JDK can also be installed to run alongside JDK 6 or JDK 7 if required by your machine.

#### Windows Requirements:

> Xamarin.Android also requires that a 32-bit Java JDK 7 (1.7) be installed.
>
> **Later versions of the JDK can also be installed alongside JDK 7**, if required by your machine.

Comment: I had to change my Visual studio settings for Xamarin to use JDK 8 in order to get my app to compile correctly.  I was getting a java error "java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main  :  Unsupported major.minor version 52.0" when using JDK 1.7

Answer (score 2):

You can use JDK 8 and the compiler will only use the features of Java that are available (you will not be able to use the latest features introduced in JDK 8 such as lambdas, otherwise you will get an error).

However, if you target Android N, you will be able to use OpenJDK 8's features, some of which are backward compatible with previous versions of Android (e.g. lambdas and method references are backwards compatible). To see what's available, check here:
[Supported Java 8 Language Features and APIs](http://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html#supported-features)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes this is true. But Android Studio tends to handle this for you, as stated by @tyczj. Lets say for example you are building an app from JDK8 for your Android 4+, but I want to run that same app on my Android 2.3, which I still have. It might not work due to compatibility issues. Although Android Studio takes care of this by allowing you to specify which version(s) you would like to support, it wouldn't hurt to look at differences between JDK8 and say, JDK6.